# django queryset ordering

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm listing queryset results and would like to add an option for choosing the order results are displayed.

I would like to pass the actual data from the database to other page for sorting.
I was able to achieve such thing by getting all objects ids and use django session to recreate a new queryset based on the order criteria.

I was thinking if there is any other way to achieve such goal?

10x

Comment: What format is the data you're passing to another page? List, dictionary, etc...

Comment: currently a list of objects IDs

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you have done..it would be easier to understand and suggest right thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm away from my development machine right now, but I think you could just pass the list of ids to a new Queryset, `pk__in=list_of_object_ids`, and then use the native `order_by` function.

For example:

```
objs = Object.objects.filter(pk__in=list_of_object_ids).order_by('value_to_order_by')
```

Anyway, that's what I would try first, though I'm sure there are better optimizations.

For example, instead of a list of object ids, you could pass a dictionary with a key:value pair that has the value you want to order by.

For example:

```
[{'obj_id':1,'obj_value':'foo'},{'obj_id':2,'obj_value':'foo'}]
```

Then use some lambda function to sort it, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/in-python-how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary).

Comment: but what if the result list is big?
Thats why I was thinking that just passing list of ids would be wiser
and then hit the DB.

I'm looking for optimizations.. (if any)

Comment: I think you might be right. Is there no other way to grab them except by ids?

Comment: search the database by ID is the preferred way and the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are currently displaying the data as a table, you could give chance to some javascript client side table sorter such as [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). There are lots of javascript table sorte.

Comment: Even so with a little bit more work you could achieve the same result using client side javascript, maybe using an array of associative arrays and a sorting algorithm, otherwise you need to pass data back to server and then you could redo the query with the same keywords you used the former time or pass the list of ids

Comment: just implemented the former option.
what do you think its better performance related solution?

Comment: Well, if the dataset is small enough, ordering in the client it's better from the performance perspective. If you need to do the sorting in server side, it depends completly in database, but, with the proper database indexes, redoing the query or filtering ids should be almost equivalent. With the later the indexes are ok for sure, so I'd probably choose the later,